# How to implement TLS client certificate authentication for webistes deloyed on Azure?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, client-certificates

I have a web app deployed on Azure. I want to restrict only devices with certificates to access the website. I know the certificate needs to be installed on the client device. But for the server side, I am not sure how to validate it. The website is developed using Java EE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could follow the steps below.

1.Navigate to your web app in the portal -> `Configuration` -> `General settings` -> set `Require incoming certificate` to `On`. If you want to allow certain paths to remain open for anonymous access, you can define exclusion paths as part of your application configuration, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth#exclude-paths-from-requiring-authentication).

[image]

2.When forwarding the request to your app code with client certificates enabled, App Service injects an `X-ARR-ClientCert` request header with the client certificate.

The client cert is available in your app through a base64 encoded value in the `X-ARR-ClientCert` request header, your app code is responsible for validating the client certificate.

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth#access-client-certificate

There are just [`ASP.NET sample`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth#aspnet-sample) and [`Node.js sample`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth#nodejs-sample) in the officilal doc, you could take a look and  implement it in java.

Comment: Thanks very much. I have done the first step while I have a concern about the second one. I wonder where I can expect to receive and deal with the request header of 'X-ARR-ClientCert'. In the web page or via server configuration?

Comment: @K.Wang From the logic of the ASP.NET sample I mentioned, it should be the web page.

Comment: great. what I did is to receive it in servlet. It works now.

Comment: In this scenario does azure verify that the client posseses the correct public key for the client certificate?

Comment: I also have questions about the above: What happens if requestor adds a `X-ARR-ClientCert` header to their request with a different (malicious?) b64 encoded public cert? Which does App Service forward? The one embedded in the original HTTPS request or the one in the user-added `X-ARR-ClientCert` header?